# How to extract a particular element from a json array in postgres?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

[image: Table parameter image]I have a table parameter having 2 columns id(integer) and param_specs(text).

the actual param_specs column looks like above pic (to simplify it check below:-
)

```
param_specs
[
{"paramName":"param1",
 "type":"string",
 "defaultValue":"tomcat7",
 "optional":false,
 "deploymentParam":false},    
{"paramName":"param123PreStopAction",
 "type":"path",
 "defaultValue":"HELLO",
 "optional":false,
 "deploymentParam":false}
]
```

So it is an array of json array and i want to fetch the `defaultValue` field of `paramName` `param123PreStopAction` i.e. HELLO.

****EDIT****
As can be seen in the image this is what my **table called parameter** looks like having two columns  I want to get **defaultValue** of each row in parameter table where paramName LIKE (%PostStopAction) or (%PreStopAction) check the bold values in image(i.e. the paramName should have either PreStopAction or PostStopAction within the actual paramName value eg 'mytomcat7**PostStopAction**'  and fetch its **defaultValue** i.e '**post-stop**'.)

There can be some rows in the table where there wont be any json having preStop or PostStop paramName like row 3 in the image

can someone help me with the query?

As JGH suggested something as follows:-

**SELECT "defaultValue" 
FROM parameter a
     CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     json_to_recordset(a.param_spec::json) AS x("paramName" text,"defaultValue" text)
WHERE "paramName”LIKE  “%PreStopAction' OR “paramName” LIKE “%PostStopAction”**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to explode your array in fields and to query them. The trick is to consider only the fields of interest.

```
Select myOutputField 
from json_to_recordset('[the array]') as (myQueryField text, myOutputField text)
where myQueryField = myCondition;
```

Or, bound to your example:

```
select "defaultValue" from json_to_recordset('
[
{"paramName":"param1",
 "type":"string",
 "defaultValue":"tomcat7",
 "optional":false,
 "deploymentParam":false},    
{"paramName":"param123PreStopAction",
 "type":"path",
 "defaultValue":"HELLO",
 "optional":false,
 "deploymentParam":false}
]') as x("paramName" text,"defaultValue" text)
where "paramName" =  'param123PreStopAction';
```

** **EDIT** **
Your data is not saved in a json column but in a text column. You would have to convert it to json (ideally, the column itself... or at least its content). Also, the `json_to_recordset` works on single items, not on sets, so you would need to use a `LATERAL JOIN` to overcome this limitation, as nicely explained [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PostgreSQL/comments/2u6ah3/how_to_use_json_to_recordset_on_json_stored_in_a/).

```
SELECT myOutputField 
FROM mytable a
     CROSS JOIN LATERAL
      json_to_recordset(a.jsonintextcolumn::json) as (myQueryField text, myOutputField text)
WHERE myQueryField = myCondition;
```

Or, bound to your example:

```
SELECT "defaultValue" 
FROM public.testjsontxt a
     CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     json_to_recordset(a.param_specs::json) as x("paramName" text,"defaultValue" text)
WHERE "paramName" =  'param123PreStopAction';
```

Comment: Hi JGH  thanks mate though above solution works but instead of passing the json array in the inner query i want something like select "defaultValue" from json_to_recordset('
select param_specs::json  from parameters) as x("paramName" text,"defaultValue" text)
where "paramName" =  'param123PreStopAction'; Can you suggest something.

Comment: Please see the edit that makes use of the lateral join

Comment: Thanks again JGH but on trying the query SELECT "defaultValue" 
FROM parameter a
     CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     json_to_recordset(a.param_specs::json) as x("paramName" text,"defaultValue" text)
WHERE "paramName" =  'param123PreStopAction';     It fails by giving message (invalid input syntax for type json).Please note the table name is parameter.Any idea why i am facing this issue?

Comment: one (or more) of your input is not following the structure you have provided in the example

Comment: like having an empty string instead of NULL

Comment: You are right JGH, within the json array the default value for some of the elements is blank.Is there any workaround for this so that I can get default value which are not blank. I am doing something like SELECT "defaultValue" FROM parameter a CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_to_recordset(a.param_specs::json) as x("paramName" text,"defaultValue" text) WHERE "paramName" LIKE '%PreStopAction' AND "defaultValue" IS NOT NULL;  (Please note that the other fields like optional can be blank as well for an array element)

Comment: please edit your question and paste all relevant data